# Sobreescribir registros Rails - UpdateOrCreate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Esoy intentando de hacer un create or update acá en rails, pero no lo he poddo llevar a termino.

### Controller

```
# POST /api/v2/excepcions
      def create
        @exception = @current_company.excepcions.find_or_create_by(alert_type_id: exception_params[:alert_type_id])
        @exception.update_attributes({color: exception_params[:color], emergente: exception_params[:emergente], sonora: exception_params[:sonora], visible: exception_params[:visible], is_active: 1})
        
        if @exception.save
          successful_response(@exception, Api::V2::ExceptionSerializer, :created)
        else
          errors_response(@exception.errors)
        end
 end
```

### Serializer

```
    class Api::V2::ExceptionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(
    :id,
    :user_mobile_id,
    :company_id,
    :alert_type_id,
    :color,
    :emergente,
    :sonora,
    :visible,
    :latitude,
    :longitude,
    :created_at,
    :is_active
  )
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :alert_type
end
```

con la finalidad de que al crear un registro de excepcion, que contenga el mismo tipo de alerta, lo sobreescriba, actualizando el color y los otros campos si es que cambiaran.
acá una imagen de ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá algo que encontré como solución en un grupo de face, que recomiendo mucho, acá el [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/rubyonrailsespa/)

utilizando una funcion del activeRecords, acá la [docu](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by)

### Metodo create

```
 # POST /api/v2/excepcions
  def create
    @exception = @current_company.excepcions
                   .find_or_initialize_by(alert_type_id: exception_params[:alert_type_id])
    @exception.assign_attributes(exception_params)

    return errors_response(@exception.errors) unless @exception.save

    successful_response(@exception, Api::V2::ExceptionSerializer, :created)

  end
```

Entonces:

### Resultado esperado

Por ej: Al crear una alerta con el tipo "Alerta GPS", si ya existe, actualiza los parametros: color, y los que contenga. de lo contrario, la crea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]